# Is it suitable to use angular with falcor?

Tags: angularjs, falcor

I am just getting familiar with falcor and I intend to use it in my angular project. What worries me is that I cannot see almost any examples of using angular with falcor.

Has anybody used this combination and if yes can You please refer to some examples. For example, what is better to be used here: $http or $resource with falcor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Falcor with Angular, but it is a bit clunky, because Falcor is designed to bind paths directly from the views, but it returns promises while Angular does not accept promises in bindings. You will have to make requests from controllers or services, and then update the `$scope`. Falcor will handle the HTTP requests for you so you don't need `$http` or `$resource`. Since Falcor doesn't know about Angular, don't forget to call `$scope.$apply` from the callbacks of Falcor requests.

See [this project](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception) for an example (I am the author).

Alternatively, there is a project named [ng-falcor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-falcor) on npm that might help you.